# How is the config variable vulnerable to content spoofing?

Tags: flash, xss, spoofing

I'm working on a project that has asked we remove risk areas from current work. As a result the attention was brought to the value set to config variables in some of our embedded flash content, for example:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://www.somedomain.com/videoplayer/flowplayer.swf" width="640" height="360">                     <param name="movie" value="https://www.somedomain.com/videoplayer/flowplayer.swf"/><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/><param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':[{'url':'https://www.somedomain.com/videoplayer/videos/index.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}"/></object>
```

What's unclear to me is how a user would do this.
Can someone explain or provide an example of how a user could inject content using value="config={...}?

Answer (score 0):

In your browser, open the console. If this is not already the case load JQuery:

```
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.setAttribute('src', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js');
document.body.appendChild(scr);
```

Reload the flash object with modified parameters:

```
$('[name="flashVars"]').html('
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
          data="https://www.somedomain.com/videoplayer/flowplayer.swf"
          width="640" height="360">
  <param name="movie"
         value="https://www.somedomain.com/videoplayer/flowplayer.swf"/>
  <param name="allowFullScreen value="true"/>
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
  <param name="flashVars" 
         value="config={'evil':true}"/>
  </object>
');
```

Everything on client side can be manipulated by user, so don't rely on it.